# Linq query to get shared items in a sublist

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a class that has a property which is a List, I will name this class A. Then I have a `List<A>`.

I need a LINQ for objects to get all the objects B that are present on ALL the items on the `List<A>`.

Example to clarify:

```
var list = new List<A>
           {
             new A { B = new List<B> { B1, B2, B3, B4 } }
             new A { B = new List<B> { B3, B4, B5, B6 } }
             new A { B = new List<B> { B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 } }
           };
```

The query must return the objects B3 and B4 because are the only ones contained on all the `List<A>` objects.

Comment: You have a class A with 3 lists or a list of As each with a list containing Bs?

Comment: That was extremely confusing (for me anyway). Could you write a LITTLE bit of actual code to show what you want returned?

Comment: @tvan: A list of As each with a list containing Bs, thanks

Comment: @aquinas: rewrited the question to make it more clear. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a list of lists and you want the elements that are in all the inner lists, you can use a combination of `Aggregate` and `Intersect`, like this:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> listOfLists = new string[][] {
    new string[] { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4" },
    new string[] { "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6" },
    new string[] { "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6" }
};

IEnumerable<string> commonElements = listOfLists.Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);
```

Comment: Haven't used the overload that only takes a single delegate, so forgot this can be done. Kudos for simplicity!

Comment: @SPFiredrake Thanks. My first thought was to use a lambda, but then I realised it would just be passing both of its parameters straight into `Enumerable.Intersect`.

Comment: Thinking about this, you'd still need a Select prior to the Aggregate call, as the B collection is a property. That only slightly changes it though, to `list.Select(tr => tr.B).Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect)`.

Comment: @SPFiredrake Yes, you're right. I created a simple example to show the technique, so I didn't have to create dummy `A` and `B` types.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `Intersect()` provided there is at least one element and your class `B` has an adequate implementation of equality / `GetHashCode()`:

```
IEnumerable<B> allBs = list[0].B;
foreach (var item in list.Skip(1))
{
    allBs = allBs.Intersect(item.B);
}
```

I see no benefit of a "pure" Linq solution here besides adding complexity.

Comment: +1 simple and clever. The only benefit of pure LINQ, imo, is a learning.

Comment: But IMHO harder to read than the solution of Matthew. Anyway a valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the Equals/GetHashCode are properly defined for objects of type B, then this is actually somewhat simple:

```
_listToQuery.Aggregate(
    _listToQuery.First().B, 
    (seed, nextItem) => { seed = seed.Intersect(nextItem.B); return seed; })
```

Or, another way:

```
_listToQuery.SelectMany(tr => tr.B)
    .GroupBy(tr => tr)
    .Where(tr => tr.Count() == _listToQuery.Count)
    .Select(tr => tr.Key)
```

Comment: Nice to see that is somewhat simple for you :) I find your query complex ... I will try it, thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why you set `seed = seed.Intersect(nextItem.B)` rather than just doing `(seed, nextItem) => seed.Intersect(nextItem.B)`?

Comment: The query might be complex, but the concept is easy enough. Intersecting lists of like types will get you the duplicates between the two lists, and you just keep chaining them together until you're done. The second method will flatten out the respective lists of A, so that instead of having a `List<A>` which is really just `List<List<B>>`, you just have a `List<B>`. Grouping by the item itself will then transform it into (for simplicity sake) `Dictionary<B, Enumerable<B>>`, so the key is the distinct item in question and the value is the list of B's that match that grouping.

Comment: Sanity check. I've always ran into problems because I keep forgetting that I had to return the seed value, so it's just a force of habit. You are correct though, as lambda expressions that just perform a single statement are treated as a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this is to create a list of all the B's then find out which ones occur more than once by grouping them by some unique identifier (or just the object if they are comparable).  Once they are grouped, select those where the number of instances is greater than 1, using the first instance of each grouping as the canonical representative.

```
var selection = list.SelectMany( a => a.B )
                    .GroupBy( b => b.UniqueID, b => b )
                    .Where( b => b.Count() > 1 )
                    .Select( b => b.First() );
```

Comment: I like your idea ... all I need to make it work is to use a groupby with a count and take all items that has a count equals to the number of items on List<A>, this way I will know that each item contains it. Thanks.